# Spring MVC: error pages and principal information

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to implement custom error pages for web application. I use the following way:

web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/404/</location>
</error-page>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login ... />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403/" />
    ....
</http>
```

Both pages are handled by appropriate controller. But it seems that the `principal` is unaccesable in this case i.e. I can't get any information about currently logged in user.

Is it default behaviour or I have an error in code?

Thank you

UPD #1:
My config:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-data.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-mail.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: how do you map the security filter in web.xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access principal data from error pages, you need to map your spring security filter as:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```