# how to include error page in spring MVC 3.0?

Tags: spring, stack-trace

**how  to include error page in spring MVC 3.0 ?**
  How show error page on exception occurrence .

```
<http auto-config="true">       
    <access-denied-handler ref="my403" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />    
</http> 

<beans:bean id="my403" class="com.mkyong.web.exception.MyAccessDeniedHandler">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="403" />     
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Which authentication is used?

Comment: username and passward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See either [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521623/spring-mvc-error-pages-and-principal-information) on stackoverflow or work with `@ControllerAdvice`.

You can build your own error controller quite easy:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "generalError";

final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
StringBuilder stackTraceString = new StringBuilder("");


@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    //System.out.println("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
    mav.addObject("errorMessage", exception.getMessage());

    for (StackTraceElement element : exception.getStackTrace() ){
        stackTraceString.append( element );
        stackTraceString.append( NEW_LINE );
      }
    mav.addObject("stackTrace", stackTraceString);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    return mav;
  }
}
```